# Is there a more CPU-efficient way to iterate over JSON than Array.map() given my specific circumstances?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I currently have a JavaScript program that iterates over JSON from an API. The only variable I need from the JSON is `mana_cost` which will always be available in one of two data structures:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "mana_cost": "{2}"
    },
    {
      "mana_cost": "{G}"
    },
    //etc...
  ]
}
```

or...

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "card_faces": [
        {
          "mana_cost": "{U}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My program creates an Array called `possibleManaCosts` which has every **unique** value of `mana_cost` found within the JSON, like so:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(body); //body is the JSON requested from the API
var possibleManaCosts = [];

obj.data.map(function(e) {    
    t = (e.card_faces == undefined) ? e.mana_cost : e.card_faces[0].mana_cost

    if (possibleManaCosts.indexOf(t) == -1) {
        possibleManaCosts.push(t);
    }
});
```

My question is whether or not there is a more efficient solution CPU-wise. Are there any Array functions I could be using in addition to `Array.map()` that I'm missing? Is cutting `Array.map()` in favor of another function better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to this link a for loop would be the best performing. [loop performance analysis](https://github.com/dg92/Performance-Analysis-JS)

Comment: The second JSON example you provided isn't valid. You have the key-value `"card_faces": [..]` within an array.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `.map` solely in order to iterate over an array. I really don't know why so many people do that when there is already `.forEach` which is WAY more natural than the somewhat arcane `.map()` (for people who don't know what a mathematical mapping is). To explain - `.map` iterated over each member and then *transforms* it into another item by passing it through *the mapping function* you supply. So you get a new array of the same size with each item transformed to another.

Comment: @Abion47 Fixed that typo, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `map` / `forEach` can't really be helped (and you really should be using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if you're not performing a projection). You could replace it with a `for` loop, but that will only give you a *very slight* speed improvement:

```
var possibleManaCosts = {};

for (var i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
  t = (e.card_faces == undefined) ? e.mana_cost : e.card_faces[0].mana_cost

  if (possibleManaCosts.indexOf(t) == -1) {
    possibleManaCosts.push(t);
  }
}
```

What could be more significant is to remove the `indexOf(t)`. Instead of keeping an array of unique `possibleManaCosts`, keep an object with each key being a value of `mana_cost`:

```
var possibleManaCosts = {};

for (var i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
  t = (e.card_faces == undefined) ? e.mana_cost : e.card_faces[0].mana_cost

  possibleManaCosts[t] = true;
}

possibleManaCosts = Object.keys(possibleManaCosts);
```

However, even this would be a hardly noticeable improvement unless you're looping over a *very* large array. You should optimize first for readability, only worry about relatively minor performance tweaks unless you have actual evidence that this portion of code is harming user experience. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).

Answer (score 1):

In case you are parsing it from a json string anyway and you don't have a object as input, then you can perform it while parsing, with no additional effort (exactly your case). But, Otherwise this idea is not good, if you have object as input and you are creating a json string to parse it back, so that you can iterate recursively very easily. as per performance that's very bad, but simple.

```js
var inputStr = `{
      "data": [
        {
          "mana_cost": "{2}"
        },
        {
          "mana_cost": "{G}"
        },
        {
          "nested": { "mana_cost": "{Z}" }
        },
        {
          "mana_cost": "{G}"
        }
      ]
    }`,
    res = {},
    parsedData = JSON.parse(inputStr, (k, v) => {
                    k==="mana_cost" && (res[v] = true);
                    return v;
                  })
 console.log(Object.keys(res));
```

Comment: That isn't filtering the unique values but it's still a very clever solution - you don't need to go over the whole structure multiple times and the parsing callback is a really simple to implement. Adding a uniqueness filter is going to be trivial by building up an object or Set with all encountered values as you go along.

Comment: My solution has nothing to do with unique value. that's a separate thing, it says all about how to get all nested value froma json string. for unique values we can use a hash object for res instead of array, and then do`res[k]=true` and at last `Object.keys(res)` will be the unique results

Comment: "*My solution has nothing to do with unique value. that's a separate thing*" I agree - you were pointing out something I very frequently forget about - the `JSON.parse` callback that can be leveraged to extract the values without walking the resulting object. It's still easy to adjust that to extract only unique values by dumping them into a Set instead of an array. To clarify - I don't mean that you should change your answer. My comment was intended as just that - a comment.

Comment: I agree with you. Neither I claimed anywhere that we should do this to find nested keys in object for better performance. But, I repeat **but**.... if you have a string as input and that anyway need to be parsed, you really cannot reduce that effort. and you know that the key can exists in any level, and you need all the (unique) values of that key, then (only then) it's better to find them along with parse. I have updated the answer for unique values. and I appreciate your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

The second example provided in the question isn't valid JSON, so I will ignore it for now. Regarding the first example, a simple `for` loop will likely be by far the most performant:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(body);
var costs = {};

for (let i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
  costs[data.mana_cost] = true; // Or some other value
}
```